# status=1/FAILURE starting kubelet

Tags: systemd, services, systemctl, kubernetes

I've just installed `kubeadm`, `kubelet`, `kubectl` `1.26.0` using `apt install` command. When I try `systemctl status kubelet`, I get the following result:

```
● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
             └─10-kubeadm.conf
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-12-10 16:46:24 PST; 9s ago
       Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/
    Process: 6420 ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 6420 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 103ms
```

I don't know what is the problem with that and how can I fix it?

This is also the result for `kubectl config view`:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://192.168.1.2:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: DATA+OMITTED
    client-key-data: DATA+OMITTED
```

And the content of `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf`:

```
  GNU nano 6.2                                           /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf                                                    
# Note: This dropin only works with kubeadm and kubelet v1.11+
[Service]
Environment="KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS=--bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf"
Environment="KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS=--config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
# This is a file that "kubeadm init" and "kubeadm join" generates at runtime, populating the KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS variable dynamically
EnvironmentFile=-/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env
# This is a file that the user can use for overrides of the kubelet args as a last resort. Preferably, the user should use
# the .NodeRegistration.KubeletExtraArgs object in the configuration files instead. KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS should be sourced from this file.
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/kubelet
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS
```

Kubernetes version:
`kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"26", GitVersion:"v1.26.0", GitCommit:"b46a3f887ca979b1a5d14fd39cb1af43e7e5d12d", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-12-08T19:57:06Z", GoVersion:"go1.19.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`

Cloud being used: `localhost`

Installation method: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/

Host OS:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

CNI and version:
CRI and version:

This is `/.kube/config` file:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCk1JSUMvakN>
    server: https://192.168.1.2:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCk1JSURJVENDQW>
    client-key-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBSU0EgUFJJVkFURSBLRVktLS0tLQpNSUlFb2dJQkFBS0>
```

This is `/etc/containerd/config.toml` file:

```
[plugins]
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.runc]

  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.runc.options]
      SystemdCgroup = true

  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri"]
  sandbox_image = "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.2"
```

EDIT: This is the result for `journalctl -xu kubelet.service`:

```
Dec 06 22:14:42 a systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit kubelet.service has finished successfully
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit kubelet.service has finished successfully.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 11743.
Dec 06 22:14:43 a kubelet[85576]: I1206 22:14:43.254559   85576 server.go:413] "Kubelet version" kubeletVersion="v1.25.4"
Dec 06 22:14:43 a kubelet[85576]: I1206 22:14:43.254699   85576 server.go:415] "Golang settings" GOGC="" GOMAXPROCS="" GOTRACEBACK=""
Dec 06 22:14:43 a kubelet[85576]: I1206 22:14:43.255385   85576 server.go:576] "Standalone mode, no API client"
Dec 06 22:14:43 a kubelet[85576]: I1206 22:14:43.295733   85576 server.go:464] "No api server defined - no events will be sent to API server"
Dec 06 22:14:43 a kubelet[85576]: I1206 22:14:43.295813   85576 server.go:660] "--cgroups-per-qos enabled, but --cgroup-root was not specified.  defaulting to /"
Dec 06 22:14:43 a kubelet[85576]: E1206 22:14:43.296299   85576 run.go:74] "command failed" err="failed to run Kubelet: running with swap on is not supported, please disable swap! or set --fail-s>
Dec 06 22:14:43 a systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Current command vanished from the unit file, execution of the command list won't be resumed.
Dec 06 22:14:43 a systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit kubelet.service has exited.
```

Comment: Try running `sudo journalctl -xu kubelet.service` and the output in your question. You might get a more detailed logs about the error in that service by using `journalctl`

Comment: @EdgarMagallon: I added that at the end of the question.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon: I don't know why it shows my `kubelet version` as `1.25.4` while I have removed `1.25.4` version by `apt remove kubelet` command and reinstalled it via `apt install kubelet` command and now on it is `1.26.0` version.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon: I guess somewhere it still looks for previous configuration and I don't know where it is to update it?

Comment: Not sure why the service stills uses the old version (but maybe that's not the main problem). In the journal output you got: `failed to run Kubelet: running with swap on is not supported, please disable swap`

Comment: Try adding in the file `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf:` the next line: `Environment="KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--fail-swap-on=false` or you might try to disable the swap by using `swapoff -a` (but as far as I know you will have to comment the swap partition in /etc/fstab, otherwise on next boot the swap will be enabled again.)

Comment: @EdgarMagallon: I added `Environment="KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--fail-swap-on=false` and had commented out `swap` partition in `/etc/fstab` but still I get the same error. `systemctl daemon-reload` also couldn't help.

Comment: Try rebooting the system. But I'm not sure if that will work. Also check if kubectl is running under `snap`. When you install some software from apt this sometimes is installed with snap instead of apt

Comment: @EdgarMagallon: What is the problem with `snap`?

Comment: I've noticed sometimes does not work properly (it seems for systemd services). Maybe it's a bad configuration in the snap, I do not know. But time ago, a user asked about `ngrok` was failing when he run it via systemd service. The solution was to install `ngrok` via `apt` instead of `snap`.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon: According to my research it seems the problem is with `https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/` HAproxy, because I have only one machine and node. I don't know if I have activated it or how can I inactivate it?

Comment: I don't know about kubernetes in general so I'm not sure if your problem is related to that (but I don't think so). However I saw you posted another question and got an answer, I hope that helps you !